# Unable to read file Node 8.9.1

Tags: javascript, node.js

Documentation says I use `fs.readFileSync`. Javascript console says that's not defined.

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_threadpool_usage

```
var fs = require('fs');

class MonsterData {
}

MonsterData.data = [];

let filename = "./gennedmons";
MonsterData.data = fs.readFileSync("filename", "utf8");

export default MonsterData;

TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function[Learn More]
```

How do I read a file?

Full console.log:

```
loading pref showConsoleLogs before prefs were initialised, you will not get the correct result  content-script.bundle.js:333:7
"Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: https://fb dot me /react-devtools"  ReactDOM.js:71:9
TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function[Learn More]  bundle.js%20line%203082%20%3E%20eval:18:20
./src/App.js

/Users/quantum/pokemon/react/src/App.js
  2:8  warning  '$' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)
  webpackHotDevClient.js:196:7
./src/Data/MonsterData.js

/Users/quantum/pokemon/react/src/Data/MonsterData.js
  8:5  warning  'filename' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)
```

Full `npm start` log:

```
Compiling...
Compiled with warnings.

Warning in ./src/App.js

/Users/quantum/pokemon/react/src/App.js
  2:8  warning  '$' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)


Warning in ./src/Data/MonsterData.js

/Users/quantum/pokemon/react/src/Data/MonsterData.js
  8:5  warning  'filename' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)


You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It works fine when I test it in that version of Node.js.

Comment: `fs.readFileSync(filename,"utf8")` .. `readFileSync` is standard in `fs` module.. it can't be possible that you get that error from that snippet..  update your question with the full error /stack trace..

Comment: Sure, Pasted in console.log + npm start output

Comment: Are you running this code in node.js on a server? Or using something like webPack and running it in the browser?  There is no `fs` module in the browser.

Comment: yes, it looks like you are trying to use `fs` module in browser, it doesn't exist.. alternatively you can load using http requests/ajax or run an prebuild command to create your file so you can easily render it into your app with html  or somehow ..

Comment: Oh, thank you. I misunderstood what the code was doing. I thought by running with npm start it would be compling that thru npm